# How to send raw input as if from keyboard or mouse?

Tags: python, mouse

I am trying to write a macro using python.
I want it to do a repeated task within another program.
I believe the program that I am attempting write this macro only 
accepts raw input from keyboard and mouse input stream.
Using python libraries such as pynput.mouse, mouse, pyautogui, so on
seem to be sending a different type of keyboard/mouse input that the program
will not recognize.  (Those libraries do work to control and move the mouse
around my computer screen but do not work in the program)
It was suggested that the program accepts only input directly from the keyboard
and mouse (ports?).

How can I write code that sends data as "raw" to the program, or reroute it through the correct (port?) input stream so that the program reads it as "raw"

I hope I was able to explain this clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following post: [ctypes mouse_events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263608/ctypes-mouse-events)
It explains how to do this with raw win32 messages which will do the trick.