# Replicating Mouse clicks NameError

Tags: python

I'm trying to incorporate mouse events. I got this code from the link [ctypes mouse_events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263608/ctypes-mouse-events)
The code there had an error so I changed some part of the code into making it into an integer.

```
import win32gui, win32api, win32con, ctypes
class Mouse:
    """It simulates the mouse"""
    MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x0001 # mouse move 
    MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x0002 # left button down 
    MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x0004 # left button up 
    MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x0008 # right button down 
    MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x0010 # right button up 
    MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020 # middle button down 
    MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x0040 # middle button up 
    MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800 # wheel button rolled 
    MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = 0x8000 # absolute move 
    SM_CXSCREEN = 0
    SM_CYSCREEN = 1

    def _do_event(self, flags, x_pos, y_pos, data, extra_info):
        """generate a mouse event"""
        x_calc = int(65536 * x_pos / ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(self.SM_CXSCREEN) + 1)
        y_calc = int(65536 * y_pos / ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(self.SM_CYSCREEN) + 1)
        return ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(flags, x_calc, y_calc, data, extra_info)

    def _get_button_value(self, button_name, button_up=False):
        """convert the name of the button into the corresponding value"""
        buttons = 0
        if button_name.find("right") >= 0:
            buttons = self.MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN
        if button_name.find("left") >= 0:
            buttons = buttons + self.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN
            # time.sleep(0.1) 
            # self.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP
        if button_name.find("middle") >= 0:
            buttons = buttons + self.MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN
        if button_up:
            buttons = buttons << 1
        return buttons

    def move_mouse(self, pos):
        """move the mouse to the specified coordinates"""
        (x, y) = pos
        old_pos = self.get_position()
        x =  x if (x != -1) else old_pos[0]
        y =  y if (y != -1) else old_pos[1]    
        self._do_event(self.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE + self.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE, x, y, 0, 0)

    def press_button(self, pos=(-1, -1), button_name="left", button_up=False):
        """push a button of the mouse"""
        self.move_mouse(pos)
        self._do_event(self.get_button_value(button_name, button_up), 0, 0, 0, 0)

    def click(self, pos=(-1, -1), button_name= "left"):
        """Click at the specified placed"""
        self.move_mouse(pos)
        self._do_event(self._get_button_value(button_name, False)+self._get_button_value(button_name, True), 0, 0, 0, 0)

    def double_click (self, pos=(-1, -1), button_name="left"):
        """Double click at the specifed placed"""
        for i in xrange(2): 
            self.click(pos, button_name)

    def get_position(self):
        """get mouse position"""
        return win32api.GetCursorPos()
```

With `mouse = Mouse()`, 
The `mouse.click((100, 100), "left")` works, but `mouse.double_click((100,100), "left")` doesn't and come out with error with "NameError: name 'xrange' is not defined"

How can I trouble shoot this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: `xrange()` was in Python 2.7. In Python 3.x you have to use `range()`

Comment: did you see mouse functions in module [PyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#mouse-functions) or [pynput](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Ah Thanks Furas.

"xrange() was in Python 2.7. In Python 3.x you have to use range()"

Just changed xrange() into range() and it works.

Also the reason why I'm not using PyAutoGUI/pynput that some of the mouse function does not properly work with certain games that uses DirectX inputs and is faulty with the mouse as well. Thus, this code should work properly in case if the PyAutoGUI/pynput does not work.